# 404 After gh-pages single-page React App deployed

Tags: node.js, reactjs, github, http-status-code-404, github-pages

#### The Problem

Trying to deploy a simple single-page app, but getting a 404 when i visit the url.

#### What I've done

1. I installed gh-pages by running this command in the app directory:

`npm install gh-pages`

2. Added a homepage property in the `package.json`

`"homepage": "https://merryface.github.io/football-app-front/"`

`merryface` is my github username and `football-app-front` is the name of the GitHub repo

3. I added the following to the "scripts" object in `package.json`.

```
"predeploy": "npm run build",
"deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
```

4. I used `npm run deploy` in the command line
5. I went into the repo settings and checked that in Options, then Github Pages, the source branch is gh--pages and /(root) for the folder.
6. Waited a long time to make sure it's not a server thing. nope, https://merryface.github.io/football-app-front/ still returns a 404
7. re-ran `npm run deploy` a couple of times when I was still getting a 404

Comment: That link takes me to a "Teemz" webapp not a 404.

Comment: huh.... that's really interesting, i'm still getting a 404

Comment: Maybe your browser cached the 404 page? Try in an incognito/private window

Comment: i have disabled cache in my devtools and i have tried on my phone, on and off the wifi, and on my wife's phone. same issue

Comment: It is now working. I wonder if it was a caching thing, I don't know, I need to learn more to be able to answer that question